# $x^2-px+1$ is a factor of $x^3-2x-3r$, where $p,r \in\Bbb R$ and $p<0$. Find the value of $p$ and the value of $r$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

$x^2-px+1$ is a factor of $x^3-2x-3r$, where $p,r \in\Bbb R$ and $p<0$. Find the value of $p$ and the value of $r$.

$$
\begin {array}{c|c|c}
x^2-px+1 & x^3-2x-3r& x+p \\
& x^3-px^2+x & \\
\hline 
&px^2-3x-3r & (1) \\
&px^2-p^2x+p & (2)
\end {array}
$$

Then by visually inspecting $(1)$ and $(2)$, $p^2=3$ and $-3r =p$ and solve this for the values of $p$ and $r$.

This seems a rather imprecise way of solving this because you have to rely on the fact that both expressions look the same. What if I continued to subtract:

$$
\begin {array}{c|c|c}
x^2-px+1 & x^3-2x-3r& x+p \\
& x^3-px^2+x & \\
\hline 
&px^2-3x-3r &  \\
&px^2-p^2x+p & \\
\hline
&(p^2-3)x-(p+3r) &
\end {array}
$$

Now my question is why can't I continue multiplying $x^2-px+1$ by $\dfrac{p^2-3}{x}$ to try to get rid of the remainder? I know it is wrong, but according to the process it should be logical that I continue to keep going until the remainder doesn't exist. I guess what I'm trying to say is what are the principles behind solving this type of questions, instead of merely being *lucky* and having two expressions looking exactly the same and just comparing them. Thanks.

Comment: Recall the process of long/synthetic division. You continue until the degree of the remainder is smaller than the divisor, and stop there. $\quad$ While there is nothing to stop you from continuing the process algebraically, you start dealing with $\frac{C}{x}$ terms that are not in the theory of polynomial division. Of course, you could come up with your own theory and figure things out from there.

Comment: Alt. hint: using Vieta's relations, the two roots of $x^2-px+1$ have sum $p$ and product $1$. Using Vieta's relations again, the third root $t$ of $x^3-2x-3r$ must satisfy $t + p = 0$ and $t \cdot 1 = 3 r$.

Answer (score 1):

You've actually done most of the job already, proving that:

$$ x^3-px^2+x = (x^2-px+1)\cdot (x+p) + [(p^2-3)x-(p+3r)]$$

So if we call:
$$
\begin{align}
A(x) &= x^3-px^2+x \\
B(x) &= x^2-px+1 \\
Q(x) &= x+p\\
R(x) &= (p^2-3)x-(p+3r)\\
\end{align}
$$

We have:
$$
A(x) = B(x)\cdot Q(x) + R(x)
$$

In order for $B(x)$ to divide $A(x)$, just like with natural numbers, we need to have the reminder to be zero, so we look for $p$ and $r$ s.t.

$$
R(x) = (p^2-3)x-(p+3r) = 0
$$

Note that we are not solving for x, be we are imposing $R(x)$ to be equal to the zero-polynomial. So the last equation needs to hold for every $x$, which means

$$
p^2-3 = 0 \\
p+3r = 0
$$

You can easily solve for $p$ and $r$ now, and you can generalize this solution to similar problems.